# Salesforce: Can we customize with .Net?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am being asked to make some developments on salesforce. Is there anyway to do it using .Net instead of Apex?

Comment: If the question has a problem, it would be very useful to make a comment or do nothing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you're trying to do, there are Web Services APIs you can call from .NET, but you can not run native .NET code on the salesforce servers.

Comment: Yes, I knew about the APIs but wondering about native .NET as I was completely overwhelmed with documentation. Thanks!